# QtWebEngine Demo Application crashes

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, webengine

When I run QtWebEngine 'fancyBrowser' demo application or my own QtWebEngine app,I get following error in runtime

> nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
>   nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
>   nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
>   nouveau: ch0: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try installing nvidia drivers instead of nouveau.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your graphic driver or just use software aceleration. Add this line in your main.cpp before starting the app. This attribute must be set before Q(Gui)Application is constructed.

```
  QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
  QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
```

Or try with OpenGL

```
  QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
  QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
```

More info:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute

Comment: I had a similar problem with Rstudio (it is quite famous bug on rstudio) It is proposed by someone to run it using the following command in terminal: 

`QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 rstudio `